# Remove the black border in the AChartEngine LineChart

Tags: android, achartengine, linechart

I am searching since yesterday and i could not find a solution to remove this black border around the Line Chart .

I have implemented achartengine for the LineChart and i want to remove the black border [ attached the image ][image]

It would be better if i could make this black colour to transparent .

I tried setting the `BackgroundColor` to `GraphicalView` also, but that didn't help .

Any related answers are welcomed .

Comment: have you tried the method drawBackground from AbstractChart?

[link](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/chart/AbstractChart.html#drawBackground(org.achartengine.renderer.DefaultRenderer, android.graphics.Canvas, int, int, int, int, android.graphics.Paint, boolean, int))

Comment: Could you please let me know , where to add this drawBackground ? in the GraphicalView ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one
I hope it will help you

```
multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF7F8"));
multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF7F8"));
```